# How to filter records of only changed rows in a table and send them to API using angular table and C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

currently after saving data in my table, I am sending complete  users list to API. But my requirement is to send only changed records based on context like absent/ present to API(not all users list). How to achieve above functionality?

```
 var request = {};
            $scope.noUnsavedData = true;
            for (var attIndex in $scope.Attendance) {
                if ($scope.Attendance[attIndex].IsMorningAbsent != $scope.savedAttendance[attIndex].IsMorningAbsent ||
                    $scope.Attendance[attIndex].IsAfternoonAbsent != $scope.savedAttendance[attIndex].IsAfternoonAbsent) {
                    $scope.noUnsavedData = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //send sms

            request["academicYearId"] = AcademicYear.getYear();
            request["date"] = $filter('date')($scope.Date.dt, 'yyyyMMdd');

            var userList = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    userList = $scope.model[i].StaffId;

                } else {
                    userList += "," + $scope.model[i].StaffId;
                }
            }

            request["userList"] = userList;

            //academicyearid, date
            if ($scope.noUnsavedData) {
                if (Status === "Absent") {
                    StaffService.resource.apiAbsentName(request, function (response) {
                        alert(response.Message);
                    });
                } else if (Status === "Present") {
                    StaffService.resource.apiPresentName(request, function (response) {
                        alert(response.Message);
                    });
                }

            }
```

Comment: You'll need to capture the changes and store them somewhere. In the past stored them in 3 lists; added, updated, removed. Use this to call the api. MAybe you'll get something out of the box these days... . But... even better:

Comment: A more modern approach would be to communicate the changes upon the actual event. So, if user clicks delete - call the API, if user modiefied a row - call the API. This way you don't need a save button, but you will need an undo button. I must say, I doesn't always fit the scenario - but I found usually it does. Sometimes with minor adjustments

Comment: What does the question have to do with ASP.NET Core or EF? Looks like you're asking how to capture changes in an HTML grid? Or your own Javascript object?